# DrawingGroup Vs DrawingVisual Transform

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

I have two methods that draw a rotated rectangle on the screen.

`RenderMethod1` renders a rectangle rotated by 30 degrees using a `DrawingVisual`

```
private static void RenderMethod1(DrawingContext dc) {
    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingVisual.RenderOpen()) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(100, 100), new System.Windows.Size(320, 80));
        context.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue, (System.Windows.Media.Pen)null, rect);
    }
    drawingVisual.Transform = new RotateTransform(30, 100, 100);
    dc.DrawDrawing(drawingVisual.Drawing);
}
```

`RenderMethod2` renders a rectangle rotated by 30 degrees using a `DrawingGroup`

```
    private static void RenderMethod2(DrawingContext dc) {
        DrawingGroup group = new DrawingGroup();
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext context = drawingVisual.RenderOpen()) {
            Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(100, 100), new System.Windows.Size(320, 80));
            context.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue, (System.Windows.Media.Pen)null, rect);
        }
        group.Children.Add(drawingVisual.Drawing);
        group.Transform = new RotateTransform(30, 100, 100);
        group.Freeze();
        dc.DrawDrawing(group);
    }
```

The output is as follows:

```
RenderMethod1
```

[image]

```
RenderMethod2
```

[image]

As you can see `RenderMethod1` and `RenderMethod2` outputs are supposed to be exactly the same but they are not. Is there anything I am doing wrong in `RenderMethod1`?

Thanks for help in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got around the problem by changing RenderMethod1 as follow and it works as expected.

```
private static void RenderMethod1(DrawingContext dc) {
    DrawingGroup drawingVisual = new DrawingGroup();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingVisual.Open()) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(100, 100), new System.Windows.Size(320, 80));
        context.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue, (System.Windows.Media.Pen)null, rect);
    }
    drawingVisual.Transform = new RotateTransform(30, 100, 100);
    dc.DrawDrawing(drawingVisual);
}
```