# Unable to print my bitmap on landscape with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, printing, bitmap

I'm writting a little wpf application using the bing maps sdk.

I'm generating a bitmap form my map and i want to be able to print this map on a A4 Sheet a landscape.

I try several method but my picture is always printed in portrait.

**Here is the code i used :**

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  
myImage.Save(ms,myImage.RawFormat);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();  

bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.StreamSource = ms;  
bi.EndInit();

var vis = new DrawingVisual();
var dc = vis.RenderOpen();
dc.DrawImage(bi, new Rect { Width = bi.Width, Height = bi.Height });
RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
dc.PushTransform(rotateTransform);
dc.Close();
var pdialog = new PrintDialog();

pdialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    pdialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
    pdialog.PrintVisual(vis, "My Image");
}
```

Note : myImage is my bitmapFile.
Note : I added a 90° transform, but no effect.

Anyone have some idea please?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Tested your code, and it works as expected, without the RotateTransform (which was ineffective anyway) and without setting the orientation twice. Note also that it is recommended to create IDisposable objects in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), like `using (var dc = vis.RenderOpen()) { ... }`. Then you do not have to close/dispose them explicitly.

Comment: So, it's maybe I printed it virtually with the Microsoft XPS printer...I will try with a pdf printer.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni any word on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recently spent a significant amount of time with the `Printing` namespace, and after reproducing the code as Clemens did, I got what was expected.  I would also agree that you should use the `using` statement as Clemens suggested.

In addition, I ran across weird activity between printing to an XPS printer and a regular printer when I was testing my own code.  Try something like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  
myImage.Save(ms,myImage.RawFormat);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();  

bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.St

reamSource = ms;  
bi.EndInit();

using(var vis = new DrawingVisual())
{
    var dc = vis.RenderOpen();
    dc.DrawImage(bi, new Rect { Width = bi.Width, Height = bi.Height });
    dc.Close();

    var pdialog = new PrintDialog();
    if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        pdialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        System.Printing.ValidationResult result = pdialog.PrintQueue.MergeAndValidatePrintTicket(pdialog.PrintQueue.UserPrintTicket, pdialog.PrintTicket);
        pdialog.PrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket = result.ValidatedPrintTicket;
        pdialog.PrintQueue.Commit();

        if(pdialog.PrintQueue.IsXpsDevice)
        {
            var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pdialog.PrintQueue);
            writer.Write(vis, pdialog.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket);
        }
        else
        {
            pdialog.PrintVisual(vis, "My Image");
        }
    }
}
```

I realize there may be some redundancies, however this is a similar approach I have followed and my code should be used to get the juices flowing, hoping that it will lead you to a solution if it isn't a solution itself.  Another though, try printing to a real printer also to test that both printing sources produce the same output.  I often found that physical printers gave me different output than virtual printers.

Also, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565002/drawinggroup-vs-drawingvisual-transform), though I'm not sure it will or won't help.

Let me know if you have any questions.